# One-Dimensional Invariant Subspace of the Right-Shift Operator on $\ell^\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces

My text asks me to show that the right-shift operator on the space of bounded sequences $\ell^\infty$ has no one-dimensional invariant subspace. It's trivial to show that a constant sequence $x_n = k$ is invariant under a right-shift, so the span of the constant sequence $x_n = 1$ is in fact a one-dimensional invariant subspace of the right-shift operator. Is there some error in my reasoning or is the text incorrect?

Comment: Doesn’t the right shift operator send $(1,1,1,\ldots)$ to $(0,1,1,\ldots)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the left-shift instead of the right-shift.

If $M$ is the one-dimensional subspace spanned by a non-zero sequence $(a_n)$ and if this is invariant under the right shift then $(0,a_1,a_2,...) =c (a_1,a_2,...)$ for some constant $c$. If $c=0$ we get $a_n=0$ for all $n$ immediately.  Otherwise we have  $0=ca_1,a_1=ca_2,...$ and these imply that $a_n=0$ for all $n$.